# i am having problems solving the capstone 1 project in hyperiondev variables and control structures. can someone help. i am beginner

Tags: user-defined-functions

A program to allow the user to access two different financial calculators: an investment calculator and a home loan repayment calculator using a graphical user interface.

Menu
User is allowed to choose which calculation they want to do by choosing either 'investment' or 'bond'.

Investment
If the user selects 'investment', they are prompted to enter the following:

The amount of money that they are depositing
The interest rate (as a percentage). Only the number of the interest rate should be entered — don’t worry about having to deal with the added ‘%’
The number of years they plan on investing for
Whether they want to calculate 'simple' or 'compound' interest
Bond
If the user selects 'bond', they are prompted to enter the following:

The present value of the house
The interest rate. E.g. 7
The number of months they plan to take to repay the bond

i am not able to solve the issue about the option of Investment and bond & Simple and compound interest.  How do get the option function to operate

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add a [Minimal, Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a menu. An if statement for the user input of investment or bond, same for compound or simple.
(Pseudocode)
If userinput = investment do:
Userinputs compound or simple
If userinput = compound do:
The calculation

You have learned if statements by this point and that is all you need to use for that issue.